# Adding Disqus to website

Tags: disqus

I am attempting to include Disqus comment count to my site. Instructions such as:

"Append #disqus_thread to the href attribute in your links. This will tell Disqus which links to look up and return the comment count. For example: 
/bar.html#disqus_thread">Link"

Makes no sense to me.

What/where is "#disqus_thread"?

Which links are they talking about?

Comment: perhaps `#disqus_thread` is a placeholder for the actual thread you would like to track in disqus? So if you have a thread "myThread" then you should use `#myThead`

Comment: @Ivaylo Slavov Thank you. I do not understand where the link is or where I should put it. I don't understand what tracking a thread is supposed to mean. I merely want to put a comment section with a comment count on each page. Is the link to connect each thread separately to the Disqus server?

Answer (score 3):

There's another part to this, which is the `count.js` script that must also be put in your page code. What it does is looks for all the link that have `#disqus_thread` appended to them, looks up how many comments are associated with that URL, and replaces the text in the link.

For example, if you have a link on your page where the HTML looks like this:

`<a href="http://example.com/path-to-article/">Comment on my page!</a>`

You would see this:

[Comment on my page!](http://example.com/path-to-article/)

If you add the Disqus comment counting script (`count.js`), and then change the HTML to this:

`<a href="http://example.com/path-to-article/#disqus_thread">Comment on my page!</a>`

You would see this (or whatever number are on that page):

[33 comments](http://example.com/path-to-article/)